# Stop Redis serwer Threads stil waiting

Tags: java, redis, jedis

I wrote Java code that connects to Redis and performs operations. When I shut down the Redis server, the thread throws an error but doesn't terminate. It's in TIMED_WAITING status, and the thread waits indefinitely. What should I do to ensure the thread doesn't wait indefinitely for the server response? I want it to simply finish its work.

I tried adding a timeout in the Jedis constructor, but it didn't work. The threads were still running.

Comment: Can you share the code of conection?

Comment: Jedis jedis = new Jedis(IP, port, timeout);

Comment: jedis.auth(user,password);

Answer (score 0):

You can set the timeout for connection and for Socket:

```
try {
    Jedis jedis = new Jedis(host, port); 
    jedis.connectTimeout(3000);// 3 seconds for connection 
    jedis.getClient().setSoTimeout(5000); // 5 seconds for Socket
} catch (JedisConnectionException e) {
    // Handle connection error
}
```

Try it and let me know

Comment: it didn't help...

Comment: The thread is still waiting? or which error you have got?